# How to set the value in the localStorage after decoding using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

My objective is to store the decoded value into the localStorage. Here is the link i got after decoding the JWT token `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "ABC"`. How to set the value in localStorage. **I want to store the value of this link as `ABC`in localStorage, not the full link**

I tried like `localStorage.setItem("name", ? )`. I couldn't able to figure it out what should i right in place of **?**.

Login.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import AuthService from '../../service/AuthService';

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            message: '',
        }
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
this.Auth = new AuthService();
    }

   componentWillMount () {
    if (this.Auth.loggedIn())
      this.props.history.replace('/');
  }
    login = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
       this.Auth.login(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(res => {
            if(res.status === 200){
                localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(res));
                this.props.history.push('/');
            }else {
                this.setState({message: res.data.message});
            }
        });
    };

    onChange = (e) =>
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6">
                            React User Application
                        </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Container maxWidth="sm">
                    <Typography variant="h4" style={styles.center}>Login</Typography>
                    <form>
                        <Typography variant="h4" style={styles.notification}>{this.state.message}</Typography>
                        <TextField type="text" label="USERNAME" fullWidth margin="normal" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <TextField type="password" label="PASSWORD" fullWidth margin="normal" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onChange}/>

                        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={this.login}>Login</Button>
                    </form>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

}

const styles= {
    center :{
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center'

    },
    notification: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: '#dc3545'
    }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

Can anyone help me in this query to set the value in localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Note: localStorage accepts only string key/value pairs

```
const value = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "ABC"';
localStorage.setItem("name", value);
```

Comment: -  Hi, But everytime the link value changes as per the user login. Instead of ABC, if other user logs in (user name="DEF") then the ink would be "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "DEF""

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this for my project.

```
/**
 * function to get or set the data to local storage.
 * If data in 2nd parameter is not passed, data is retrieved else, stored.
 * @example localStorageItem("key") - to GET data
 * localStorageItem("key", {Any: JSON object here}) - to SET data
 */

export const localStorageItem = (key, data = null) => {
    if (!data) return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    if (data) localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

Comment: Hi, do i need to write in my Login Page?. Could you please help me. I don't know much about JWT token decoding stuff

Comment: I've updated my query with login component. Could you please preview it once?